# flutter problem gradle 7.4\scripts\emabqxituwovfmtng117ez4xf

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

what should i do if in flutter error like this?

```
* Where:
Build file 'D:\StudioProjects\dindiksbynew\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not open dsl generic class cache for script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' (C:\Users\RRHP\.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\emabqxituwovfmtng117ez4xf).
   > Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I've tried changing the gradle version, still can't, please help

Answer (score 0):

been faced this issue lastweek. Its quite difficult to debug. and here my current workaroud:

`android>build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'  // upgrade my kotlin version
   ...

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'  // change this
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#apply-the-plugin

latest stable kotlin version `1.7.20`, maximum fully support only for `gradle 7.1.1`

its recommended do not use `gradle` above it.

- next

add this line  to: `android>gradle>wrapper>gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

another step, maybe its required to upgrade to java sdk 11.

hope its help.

Comment: I've remade it from scratch but still the error is at line 26